# I installed Geth on Ubuntu via PPA, what is the command to start it?

Tags: go-ethereum, ppa

I followed the [guide](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-Instructions-for-Ubuntu) for installing Geth on Ubuntu via PPA. I usually use windows so I apologise if this is a dumb question. How do I start the geth client?

Comment: Run geth --help to get more information about the options

Answer (score 1):

The command should be `geth`:

> You should now be able to run geth and connect to the network.

Answer (score 0):

You can just start `geth` using the following command:

```
$ geth
```

I prefer to start `geth` with the JavaScript console:

```
$ geth console
```

The console will allow you to execute commands like:

```
> eth.syncing
false
```

To exit the console type `exit` or press `Control-D`.

To view all the command line options:

```
$ geth help
```